# Windows 10 install on ASUS VivoBook S15 S533EA-BN117 no SSD or cursor

Tags: windows, windows-10, asus-laptop

I just bought a ASUS VivoBook S15 S533EA-BN117, and everything was perfect, but I am not able to install Windows 10 on it. I have an original Home edition I bought form a retail store in my country online. They sent the code, I downloaded the installer.

When I boot up the BIOS, I have a cursor, I am able to select the USB drive I installed windows to. It boots, but when the installation starts I suddenly lose the cursor. After some steps when I have to select the hard drive, Windows does not see the SSD in the computer.

I read, that I need to switch to Legacy mode in the BIOS, but there is no such thing in the BIOS. The only option I have in the boot settings is "Secure boot". I tried Disabled and Enabled as well for this option, no luck.

I also read I need GPT formatted disk, so I created an ISO from the official installer, downloaded Rufus and burned the USB drive with the ISO using Rufus. It automatically selected GPT, so I think thats is good, but again, no luck. No cursor and no SSD during install.

I read that a BIOS upgrade might help, I havent tried that yet. Is there any other trick I can try?

Comment: Sounds more like the image you are using lacks some drivers (of whatever part that the internal drive and touchpad rely on / are attached to). Do you get the cursor back if you boot with a USB mouse plugged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/30314/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-Optane-10-11-

This link will help you. Download F6flpy-x64, and drop the unzipped content folder onto the USB stick. Begin installing Windows 10 again. When selecting Hard Drives, Download the Drivers. Profit

Comment: worked like a charm